# iPhone 3.5mm Audio jack specification (buttons)

Tags: audio, android

I have done some research in regards to this but I seem to get conflicting requirements.

So Android defines and have published a specification for this.
https://source.android.com/devices/accessories/headset/plug-headset-spec.html

Apple on the other hand, I am unable to find out if they publish this information.
I have also found out that some Android headset (3 button) does not seem to be compatible with iPhones.

Does anybody know what methods Apple iPhone devices use for 3 button detection?
Is there somewhere a publish specification released?

Comment: It should be very similar, but you could always measure the resistance of the pins.

Answer (score 1):

Apple will give you the information to work with/duplicate the "Headset Remote and Mic" (aka the little box on each pair of EarPods that have the three buttons and microphone) if [you join their MFi program](https://mfi.apple.com/MFiWeb/getFAQ.action#1-1), as noted in the MFi FAQ and on [BoingBong when the three-button setup first came out](http://gadgets.boingboing.net/2009/03/14/we-found-the-chip-in.html). I haven't seen anyone online reverse-engineer it and publish information about how it works.